# Firebase Console Urgent Alerts Stuck in the screen

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

How can I hide the urgent Red alerts in Firebase console as it hide parts of screen while accessing it as I tried to disable all notifications but still the same
Can you please help

[image]

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase console, contact Firebase support for help.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

Given that these messages tell you that your project has been disabled because it is over its quota, I doubt you can remove them.